# VueJs DropDown Option Value is undefined when attempting to render the text value in a component v-for iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Take the following code which is essentially going to render a form stepper and for the purposes of simplifying my example I have included just one step:

```
<form-wizard :formdata="this.form_data">
    <form-tab stepindex="1" title="Title of Tab" :selected="true">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-lg-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="OptionType" class="sr-only">Option Type</label>
                <select v-model="form_data.optionType" @change="onChangeOptionType" id="OptionType">
                    <option value=""/>
                    <option v-for="option in form_data.fees" v-bind:value="option.cost">
                        {{ option.text }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form-tab>
</form-wizard>
```

For reasons I cannot understand the values are bound to the select options as expected and without error however the option text throws an error in the browser console that I cannot seem to overcome.

> Property or method "option" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

It's like for some reason it is looking out to the wider scope for the option rather than the option in the v-for loop.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to correct this but also any help to try and understand why this is even the case.

If any additional information is required to help answer please let me know.

Comment: I also don't understand yet why this is happening. Could you provide `form_data` for me so I can reproduce it? Also I'm wondering what the `v-select` property is on the select element.

Comment: @jkl Here is forrm_data (simplified) 


 form_data: {
  optionType: '',
  fee: 0,
  fees: [{
    text: 'Flat',
    cost: 50
   }, {
    text: 'House',
    cost: 110
   }, {
    text: 'Commercial',
    cost: 980
   }
  ]
 }
You can ignore v-select as I think that is a copy-paste error on my part.

Comment: do you get an error that data iteration needs a key binding? there is no v-bind:key on you v-for loop

Comment: @kengres No, just the error in my OP at the moment

Comment: Aside from the error, does the option text show up correctly for each option. What makes you think that it's the `option.text` that's to blame here? Does the error go away when you change that line to some hard-coded text? Can you confirm that your original code doesn't have a `/` at the end of the opening `option` tag?

Comment: @ProNotion please provide your data.

Comment: For whomever it may be helpful here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1m692wnb/ without reproducing the problem. The suggestion @skirtle gave on trying some hard-coded text seems like a good one to me. Also make sure that the error isn't thrown from somewhere else in the application.

Comment: @skirtle If I remove {{option.text}} the error disappears, the values are fine but no option text. If I hard code the option text it displays fine.

Comment: @jkl I will assemble a more complete example as I am not using the library you referenced in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @ProNotion ah, I was already afraid that I was wrong in assuming it being the same library.

Comment: It works fine in the JSFiddle I am preparing which was even more confusing. The only difference being was where the element my Vue instance was bound to was located. In my app I moved it so it was directly surrounding the top component and it works as expected!?

Comment: @ProNotion If you locate the `<div id="app">` element in the jsfiddle at the same location as in your app locally can you then reproduce it?

Comment: I think the issue turned out to be that I somehow ended up with nested Vue instances.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is v-bind:key on v-for

```js
<select v-model="form_data.optionType" @change="onChangeOptionType" id="OptionType">
    <option value=""/>
    <option v-for="(option, i) in form_data.fees" v-bind:key="i" v-bind:value="option.cost">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this made no difference, the same error still persists

Comment: well I run the code on my end and it's working perfectly, can you provide the whole template code please?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how that helps me. If you are looking at the code you posted in isolation I am sure that it does work fine but the problem I suspect lies somewhere in the scope of data being passed through the components.